# 403 Session expired in checkout Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, onepage-checkout, checkoutsession

I'm getting this error in the checkout page of Magento 1, what could it be?

```
Request URL: /onepage/json/payments
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Session Expired
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response header
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 08:58:49 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=497
Login-Required: true, true
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: frontend=4cdofkvhn9l1jd3nonns4ptt96; expires=Fri, 30-Nov-2018 09:58:49 GMT; path=/bin4; domain=domain.com; httponly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block


Request headers
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: frontend=4cdofkvhn9l1jd3nonns4ptt96; external_no_cache=1; adminhtml=dr6gp2ti3lvc80chrvip1u0826; _fbp=fb.1.1543566407577.1080793725
Referer: /onepage/?SID=4cdofkvhn9l1jd3nonns4ptt96
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not working with it anymore